# Unable to Plot 3d Function Using Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, subplot

I am trying to plot a 3d function in python using matplotlib.  For some reason I get the error "Invalid syntax (pyflakes E)" in the second line of the code provided when trying to plot it.  I got this part from another person, and this works for them.  The packages from matplotlib I have installed are mplot3d, cm, and Subplot.  Perhaps there is another package I need?

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12,12))
ax = fig.add_subplot(projection='3d')
```

Comment: Are you using Spyder? This is seemingly not a [maptlotlib problem](https://github.com/python-mode/python-mode/issues/1086).  Can you post the full traceback of the error message and include matplotlib version and how you installed it?

Answer (score 1):

[https://jakevdp.github.io/PythonDataScienceHandbook/04.12-three-dimensional-plotting.html#:~:text=In%C2%A0%5B3%5D%3A-,fig%20%3D%20plt.figure()%0Aax%20%3D%20plt.axes(projection%3D%273d%27),-With%20this%20three](https://jakevdp.github.io/PythonDataScienceHandbook/04.12-three-dimensional-plotting.html#:%7E:text=In%C2%A0%5B3%5D%3A-,fig%20%3D%20plt.figure()%0Aax%20%3D%20plt.axes(projection%3D%273d%27),-With%20this%20three)

It seems that you need to use `ax = plt.axes(projection = 3d)`

Comment: The syntax of the code in the question is perfectly fine. Have you tried it?

Comment: I have not actually tried it.  I guess I assumed since there is an error it won't run.  It is for a neural network model.  I am running the model right now, once it is done I will try and plot it and see if it works.

Comment: So I tried it and it ran.  That is weird I was not expecting that.  Any idea why it would be giving me a syntax error but still running?